# Back to Navigation Controller's first view in TabBar app

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I got a tabbar application.

There is only 2 tabs in the tabbar. First tab is a `NavigationController`, there are two views in the `NavigationController` - root and detail views, second is a `TableViewController`. Second works perfect, but the the first doesn't.

I start in first view (`NavigationController`). Then go in this `NavigationView` to the detail view. Then, for example, i go to the second tabbar view. Then go back to the first, but i dont see the root view, but the detail view.

How can i open the root view every time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [UITabBarController delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate) method `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  if (viewController != tabBarItemForNavControllerTab) {
    [self.navControllerInFirstTab popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  }
}
```

Also make sure that delegate is setup properly, when creating your `UITabBarController` and you change the code from my snippet to fit your controller names.

Comment: @EugeneTrapeznikov Inside the UITabBarControllers parent controller. If you're not sure how delegates work please read this [**article**](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ios/ios-design-patterns-delegation-part-2/).

Comment: can i set delegate programmatically? is self.tabBarController.delegate = self; ok for it?

Comment: Yes, and your parent controller should listen to <UITabBarControllerDelegate>